# using $(this).find correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to replace the content of data-theme below

Inside a function and footer one works....

```
     $(this).find('[data-role="footer"] h4').html(siteData.name);
     $(this).find("data-theme").html(siteData.theme);
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3></h3>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

All I want to do is replace whats in the ="a" of data-theme

What is the correct way?

Comment: All depends on what is the `this` at the moment your are using it.. Also your selector is incorrect.

Comment: and querying against attributes is done via eg `[attr]` (see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: is `$(this).find()` inside of a function? Please show us what's around it.

Comment: You may use `$(this).find('[data-theme]')` or, to be more restrictive `$(this).find('[data-theme="a"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ths what you are looking for. Replace the value of your data attribute?
  Just to make it more restrictive you can add a context.

```
  alert($('div[data-theme]','#index').data('theme'));
    $('div[data-theme]','#index').data('theme','new');
    alert($('div[data-theme]','#index').data('theme'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhRHD/

More info on this:- http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.
The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).
```

Comment: all I want to do its change data-theme="a" to data-theme="b" using jquery

Comment: Ok, I the same, I'm using jquery mobile, so I need another library for this to work?

Comment: these are the libs I have  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27250/discussion-between-pscoder-and-marko)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you're trying to change the theme attribute?

```
$(this).find("[data-theme]").attr("data-theme", "b")
```

Is that right?